# JWT Java with a public/private key pair pre-generated as files

Tags: java, security, jwt

I'm currently developing an auth server for 3 future projects. The idea is that the auth server signs and creates an access token with the private key and the 3 future projects would have a public key to verify the access token.

I generated rsa keys in pem format:

`openssl genrsa -out private.pem 4096`

`openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform PEM -out public.pem`

I then read online that java can't read these formats. So I converted them to DER format:

`openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private.pem -out private.der -nocrypt`

`openssl rsa -pubin -inform PEM -in public.pem -outform DER -out public-der`

I was then able to create and sign the access token with the private key like so:

```java
       try (InputStream privateKeyStream = Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jwt/private.der"))) {

            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyStream.readAllBytes());
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);

            String jwt = Jwts.builder()
                    .signWith(privateKey, SignatureAlgorithm.RS512)
                    .setHeaderParam("typ", SecurityConstants.TOKEN_TYPE)
                    .setIssuer(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_ISSUER)
                    .setAudience(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
                    .setSubject(uuid.toString())
                    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION))
                    .claim("rol", Arrays.asList(ERole.TRIAL.name()))
                    .compact();
            return jwt;
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AccessTokenCreationFailedException("Could not create access token!");
        }
```

Now I need to verify the token when it is used. This is how far i've gotten:

```java
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyStream.readAllBytes());
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec); // Throws exception
Jwts.parser()
     .setSigningKey(publicKey)
     .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""));
```

This throws `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Missing key encoding`

It's kind of confusing to me how to use the different key specs and what not. Anyway, how can I now verify the token with the public key? Are my keys in the wrong format? If so, I don't have a problem with recreating the keys, specific openssl commands for this would then be highly appreciated.

Comment: `publicKeyStream` is a stream from DER or PEM encoded key? What is the type of this object.

Comment: It is DER format basically the same "try with resources" line as with private key; public.der

Comment: I have no issue with your code using Java 11 and DER public key generated with openssl. Cannot reproduce.